# Treeview with Checkboxes in Python - ability to right click on Tree and add any number of parent and child nodes

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, tix

I am wanting to create a treeview in Python where I can right click on the tree and add to it at any point a parent or child node and I can keep populating the tree with parent and children checkboxes.

The parent checkboxes would be partially checked if some of the children checkboxes are checked if all the children are checked the parent would be fully checked.

There would be an unlimited number of parent and children checkboxes going several levels deep.

A report could be run that summarizes what parents and or children are checked it would report the structure as it is i.e.  parent>child>child>child

How can I accomplish this? Would I use tix or ttk or is there something else better suited ?

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JRiggles I guess this is the wrong place to ask the question. I do not know how to code this. I am trying to build a program to solve a problem and I thought by asking the above it would clarify where I need to start looking, and how to start solving the problem.

Comment: Stackoverflow is more of an "I'm seeing this error when I run my code, what am I doing wrong?" kind of place rather than a "I'm trying to make an app that does 'x', how do I do that?" kind of place. That said, you should post your code (always post your code!), and somebody might be able to point you in the right direction. I hope that helps.